# Python : How to switch from one database to another depending upon filedate in the query through 'pyodbc.connect' or something?

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

```
value_date = (pd.to_datetime('30-Oct-2019').strftime('%d-%b-%Y')).upper()   

iss_cnxn = pyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'server=abc;'
                      'database=xyz;' 
                      'trusted_connection=yes')

sql_query = ' '.join(f"""select
xxx as x,
yyy as y,
zzz as z,
from dbo.abcd P WITH(NOLOCK)
where filedate = '{value_date}'""".split())
```

What is the best way to determine the database based on the ‘filedate’ that we are querying? In the example I have hardcoded the value_date as 30th Oct 2019 but we will pass the date parameter later. Is there any function or something to switch the database based on filedate ? There should be some connection between the filedate and switching the database. Please suggest.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity. What sort of difference in date do you want? E.g is it Binary (e.g if weekday connect to database A, if weekend connect to B) or are there different versions of the database for any day?? Explain why you want to connect to a different database based on the day

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple if statement to modify the db name and use string formatting to pass the correct db name to your connection.  For example if the query_date is in the future, use db1, else use db2.  Change datetime.now() to whatever date you want.

```
from datetime import datetime
if query_date > datetime.now():
    db = 'db1'
else:
    db = 'db2'
iss_cnxn = pyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'server=abc;'
                      'database={};'.format(db) 
                      'trusted_connection=yes')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but there is another twist in the program. Let me edit the post and re-write.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the data in a create_db function.

```
def create_db_conn(value_date):
    if value_date == 'xyz':
        db = 'db1'
    else:
        db = 'db2'
    
    iss_cnxn = pyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'server=abc;'
                      'database={};'.format(db) 
                      'trusted_connection=yes')
    return iss_cnxn
```

This will make your connection dynamic according to value_date. You can write another function to close this connection as well.